# What is the difference between method and field?

Tags: scala

In Java, the difference between them is clear. But in Scala,  methods can be declared and used without parenthesis. And I also know that Uniform Access Principle is the philosophy that Scala holds. These all make the boundary between field and method vague to a new learner.

At the beginning, I thought `def` and `val` is the boundary between method and field. But it turns out that in Scala, "field" defined in subclass using `val` can override "method" defined in base class using `def`, which seems impossible in any languages I know that distinguish the concepts of field and method.

Thus I wonder:

1. Whether the concept of "field" does not exist(or is **entirely** the same thing as parameterless method) in Scala?
2. If not, what is the boundary between them?

Comment: Saying that `def` and `val` over override _each other_ is too strong of a statement. You can override a `def` with a `val`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @m-z Thanks you, I have edited my description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple. For example for a public `val` scalac generates private field to hold the value, and a getter.

```
class A {
  val x = 4
}
```

in javap you can see

```
public class A {
  private final int x;
  public int x();
  public A();
}
```

so if you had

```
trait T { def x = 1 }
```

when

```
class A extends T { val x = 4 }
```

you are overriding the method `x` from trait `T` with a getter `x` to private field `x`.

Comment: explain why can override but nothing about boundary

Comment: @yuxh I guess The first paragraph explains it. The difference between def and val is, that `val` creates a field and a getter method while `def` just creates a method. The `def` evaluates each time when you call it, val evaluates only once, on initialization and the evaluated value is stored in the field.

Comment: If we are considering def with no args, then simply use `def` if the result needs to be calculated on each access because it may change. If result can be calculated once on initialization of class, use `val`. If you need result to be calculated once on first access, use `lazy val`.

Answer (score 2):

*Major difference*

```
def f: Int = something

val v = 1
```

`f` is a method is not evaluated immediately. `f` is evaluated everytime when the `f` is called explicitly invoked or called, where as `v` is evaluated immediately.

*Notice `f` is not evaluated when declared, but `x` is immediately evaluated when declared. `f` is evaluated when explicitly called.*

```
scala> val x = { println("evaluated"); 1}
evaluated
x: Int = 1

scala> def f = { println("evaluated"); 1}
f: Int

scala> f
evaluated
res0: Int = 1

scala> f
evaluated
res1: Int = 1
```

*Inheritance*

```
trait A {
  def m: Unit
}

class B extends A {
 override val m: Unit = something
}
```

`def` can be overridden to `val` but not vice versa. we are able to do this because declaring `val m` produces a method named `m`. so its like declaring `m` in the subtype to override whats in the super type.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought `def` defines method and `val` defines field. But it turns out that in Scala, members defined using `def` and `val` can actually freely override each other in class hierarchies, which does not seems like something can be done across methods and fields in other languages that  do distinguish the difference between method and field.

Comment: @LifuHuang  def can be overridden to val but not vice versa. without loss of generality

Answer (score 2):

It becomes clear when you turn on `-print` option in compiler:

```
def m = List(1,2,3)

=> 

object iw extends Object {
  def m(): List = 
    scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(
      scala.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{1, 2, 3})
    );
  def <init>(): type = {
    iw.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
```

vs

```
val v = List(1,2,3)

=>

object iw extends Object {
  private[this] val v: List = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def v(): List = iw.this.v;
  def <init>(): type = {
    iw.super.<init>();
    iw.this.v =
      scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(
        scala.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{1, 2, 3})
      );
  ()
}
```

}

Both effectively define a method, but in the latter case initialization of the private variable happens immediately and you simply get its value, while in the former every time you call it.

Comment: Nice! For anyone else reading this you can enable this while in the REPL by typing `:settings -print`.